# How to update the value of 'origLeft' in vue-codemirror MergeView?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using vue-codemirror Merge https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror/blob/master/examples/14-merge-view.vue to show the file diff. I want to show a lot of files' diff in one vue page. However, it seems that the value of origLeft will always not change when I put a the new file's content to it (which always show the first file's content). Is there any advice to deal with this problem?

My code:

```
<template>
<div>
<codemirror ref="cmMerge" :merge="true" :options="cmOption" style="height: auto;display: inline-block; width: 100%"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
import 'codemirror/addon/merge/merge.js'
import 'codemirror/addon/merge/merge.css'
import 'codemirror/theme/idea.css'
import DiffMatchPatch from 'diff-match-patch'
import { codemirror } from 'vue-codemirror'
window.diff_match_patch = DiffMatchPatch
window.DIFF_DELETE = -1
window.DIFF_INSERT = 1
window.DIFF_EQUAL = 0

export default {
  name: 'DiffConfigList',
  components: {
    codemirror
  },
  data() {
    return {
      moduleList: [],
      viewDiffVisiable: false,
      cmOption: {
        origLeft: null,
        value: '',
        // orig: '', 
        mode: 'text/html',
        collapseIdentical: false,
        highlightDifferences: true,
        lineNumbers: true, 
        revertButtons: false,
        showDifferences: true,
        readOnly: true, 
        theme: 'idea',
        fontSize: 16,
        allowEditingOriginals: true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showFileDiff(row) {
      get_branch_master_file_content(row.origin_file_name).then(response => {
        this.cmOption.origLeft = response.master // this assignment only works on the first file 
        this.cmOption.value = response.branch
      }).catch(error => {
        this.$message({
          showClose: true,
          message: error,
          type: 'error'
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```